# check if key or value exists from one input

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, input

I have a dictionary that is similar to

```
my_dict ={'Bob' : 11, 'Sandy':12, 'Katy':13}
```

and I have a code that checks if the input matches the value

```
user_input = input('Enter a name')
while my_dict.get(user_input) == None:
        chosenSchool = input('please enter a correct name')
```

and then other code happens
so that works out fine, but Im trying to have code commence if the user has typed the correct value from `user_input`, i tried something like this, and i made a list of both the keys and values from `my_dict`, `person_name`, and `person_code`.

```
if   user_input.isdecimal():
        while user_input not in my_dict.values():
            chosenSchool = input("enter a correct name or number")
        numval = int(user_input)
        pos_of_Name = person_code.index[numval]
        Name_person = person_name[pos_of_name]
```

So eventually the name of this person should be `Name_person`, and the code `numval`, but clearly I am doing something wrong. I could probably make a function or something as well

Comment: I can help you, but I've no idea what your question says. Is there any way you can add more context to your question ??

Comment: Your *while* loops will run indefinitely if *user_input* is not found (as a key in your first code fragment or as a value in the second fragment). Can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve and also show the declarations for *person_code* and *person_name*

Comment: @basicmojo basically i have a dictionary, and I am trying to make it so that the user can enter a key or a value(the person name, or their code), and have code run from that. Like after that, the code will essentially run the same regardless of if I have the key or value inputted, but I am supposed to have both inputted.

Comment: @DarkKnight person_code and person_name aren't really important, I just thought I would have to make a list of the keys and values from my_dict in order to somehow check if the inputted code matches the code value from the dictionary,

Comment: @DarkKnight I guess there is also the problem of whenever a user does enter an incorrect number, even if you enter the correct name, it still treats it as a number, so the code won't run

Comment: You have a problem with your design (notwithstanding the faulty code you've shown). Asking a user to input a value to be looked up in a dictionary can lead to ambiguous results because keys are unique but values are not. For example, in your sample dictionary, change Sandy's value to 11. What would happen if you ask your user for a value and they enter 11? Does that equate to Bob or Sandy or both?